# sessionAsSigner.getDatabase returning null

Tags: xpages

I am attemtpting to use `SessionAsSigner.getDatabase` in SSJS to access a db on a different server. But it always returns `null`. For example I use:

```
var db = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("canonical name of server","log.nsf", false);
```

Comment: Does the target server list the server your XPage is running on as a "trusted server" in the Domino Directory?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably error in server security setting. You can read this page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086111

Answer (score 1):

When you use sessionAsSigner the server you are connecting to is able to authenticate who you are when you log in.

When you are running code on the server (A) and you need to talk to another server (B), then the first server has authenticate with A credentials. It cannot authenticate as you.

To allow it to run correctly you need to set up server A as a trusted server on server B.

You can set [trusted servers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/discover/v8r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.discovery.es.ad.doc/security/iiysasecnotts.htm) in your server document.

You can programatically check if this is set using the `NotesSession.isTrustedSession()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you code is signed with different signers. 
Try to resign the database with your or the servers id.

That will probably fix your problem.

Comment: Not sure about this one, in that case getSessionAsSigner returns null, so above code would fail with NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

The Server you are using needs to have access and a connection document to the server you want to access. So The first thing to do is: check If your server is listed in the "Who can Access this Server" Field in the Server document. Then check the Trusted Servers Section. Then check the ACL of your log (your executing server and the XPage signer need to have access to log.nsf)